# Python error : SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax

```
 def ElfouhailySpectrum(self,k):  

          ### parameters calculues ######

        ElfouhailySpectrumList = []

        S = np.zeros(np.shape(Bh))
        S = Bh + Bl

        Delta = np.tanh(np.log(2.)/4. + 4.*(self.c(k)/sself.cp)**2.5+0.13*(self.nUstar/self.cm)*(self.cm/self.c(k))**2.5)
        G = 1./(2.*np.pi)*(1+Delta*np.cos(2*self.Phi)


        ElfouhailySpectrumList = [S, nan_to_num(1./(k**4)*S*G),Delta]
        return ElfouhailySpectrumList
```

It returns :

```
ElfouhailySpectrumList = [S, nan_to_num(1./(k**4)*S*G),Delta]
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't have a clue of what is going wrong.
I thought about declaration but I declared it and it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a close parenthesis here:

```
G = 1./(2.*np.pi)*(1+Delta*np.cos(2*self.Phi))
```